# How to crop an image on the right to match the width of a containing element?

Tags: html, css, image, crop

I searched the internet, but couldn't find the exact solution.

If I have an image like this:

> =====/     /====================================

I am looking to get a result like this:

> =====/     /=====

Not resized, not centered, only cropped on the right to match the width of the containing `div`.

How can I do this?

Comment: No worries on the images. A little code is usually helpful, though. I have a few ideas for what the problem is. Can you post your code or make and save something on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be using the image as a background of the `crop` element, instead of a separate element within itself.

For example:

```
.crop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('some-path/some-image-to-be-cropped');
}
```

### [See JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V42mF/)

Comment: Bit modified - width to 100% to match div size. Thanks!